# How do I get DateTime.now and DateTime.strptime to use the same timezone?

Tags: ruby

If I do:

```
1.9.3p125 :018 > DateTime.now
=> Mon, 30 Jul 2012 16:16:57 -0700
```

The time has -0700...

Yet if I do:

```
DateTime.strptime(Time.now.to_i.to_s, "%s")
=> Mon, 30 Jul 2012 23:24:46 +0000
```

Then it's +0000...  How do I get these to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.strptime(Time.now.to_i.to_s, "%s").to_time.localtime
```

or

```
DateTime.strptime(Time.now.to_i.to_s, "%s").change(:offset => "-0700")
```